# Increase the spacing of references

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I am using Texmaker and the spacing between lines is too close in my references. I want to increase it. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Here is my current latex setup

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}



\usepackage[4committee,masters,standard,nonsequential]{cuthesis}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[space]{cite}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[indent,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, linkcolor  = black}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{pdfsync}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\onehalfspacing

\newcommand{\Sec}[1]{Sec.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ch}[1]{Chap.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\App}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Fig}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Figure}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Eq}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.e., }
\newcommand{\eg}{e.g., }
\newcommand{\fT}{\textit{f}\textsubscript{T}\ }
\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{{\color{green} [#1]}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}


\begin{document}







\reffile{ref}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}




\abstract{abstract}
\acknowledgements{acknowledgements}
\nomenclature{nomenclature}
\preface{preface}
\dedication{dedication}
\newchapter{chapter1}
\newchapter{chapter2}

%\newchapter{chapter3}
%\newchapter{chapter4}
%\newchapter{chapter5}
%\newchapter{chapter6}
%\newchapter{chapter7}
%
%
% Include any appendices.
%\newappendix{appendixA}
%\newappendix{appendixB}





\end{document}
```

This is what my ref file looks like

```
@article{serdes_pam4,
  author={Seual, Yoav and Laufer, Amir and Khairj, Ahmad and Krupnik, Yoel and Cusmai, Marco and Levin, Itamar and Gordon, Ari and Saban, Yaniv and Rahinskj, Vitali and Ori, Gadi and Familia, Noam and Litski, Stas and Warshavsky, Tali and Virobnik, Udi and Horwitz, Yeshayahu and Balankutty, Ajay and Kiran, Shiva and Palermo, Samuel and Li, Peng Mike and Cohen, Ariel},
  booktitle={2022 IEEE International Solid- State Circuits Conference (ISSCC)}, 
  title={A 1.41pJ/b 224Gb/s PAM-4 SerDes Receiver with 31dB Loss Compensation}, 
  year={2022},
  volume={65},
  number={},
  pages={114-116},
  doi={10.1109/ISSCC42614.2022.9731794}}
```

Here is cuthesis:

```
\@ifundefined{DeclareOption}{}{% LaTeX2e option
\ProvidesPackage{cuthesis}[2008/08/24 \space  v 1.2]

\DeclareOption{manuscript}{\def\@wantmanuscript{true}}
\DeclareOption{standard}{}

\DeclareOption{phd}{\def\@phddissertation{true}}
\DeclareOption{masters}{}

\DeclareOption{nocopy}{\def\@nolibraryrights{true}}
\DeclareOption{copy}{}

\DeclareOption{noleadpages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}}
\DeclareOption{leadpages}{}

\DeclareOption{norefbib}{\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{refbib}{}

\DeclareOption{noextrapages}{\def\@noleadpages{true}\def\@norefbib{true}}
\DeclareOption{extrapages}{}

\DeclareOption{nonsequential}{\def\@wantnonsequential{true}}
\DeclareOption{sequential}{\def\@wantsequential{true}}

\DeclareOption{4committee}{\def\@fourcommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{5committee}{\def\@fivecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{3committee}{\def\@threecommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{2committee}{\def\@twocommittee{true}}
\DeclareOption{1committee}{\def\@onecommittee{true}}

\ProcessOptions
}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  % standard
  \@ifundefined{@wantnonsequential}{}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}
}{
  % manuscript
  \@ifundefined{@wantsequential}{\def\@nonsequential{true}}{}
}

\def\bibliocite#1{%
  \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{#1}}\fi}

\@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{

\@ifundefined{@extra@b@citeb}{
% this is for use without the cite package
\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\hbox{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
}
{
% this is for use with the cite package
\def\@nocite#1{\xdef\@no@sparg{\@ignsp#1 \! }% remove *ALL* spaces
 \if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout {\string\citation {\@no@sparg}}\fi
 \if@filesw \immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@no@sparg}}\fi}
}

}
{

% this section is basically chapterbib

\newenvironment{cbunit}%
{\global\advance\c@inputfile\@ne \xdef\the@ipfilectr{@-\the\c@inputfile}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}}%
{\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\@extra@binfo{\@exele@b@citeb}}%
  }

\let\cb@include\include
\def\include#1{\clearpage \cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \cb@include{#1}%
\refsforcb%
\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\newcommand\cbinput[1]{\cbunit \xdef\@currentipfile{#1}%
  \input{#1}\global\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname\endcbunit}

\@ifundefined{@extra@binfo}{%
  \def\bibcite#1#2{\global\@namedef{b@#1\@extra@binfo}{#2}}%
}{}

\@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}{%
 \def\@citex[#1]#2{%
   \let\@citea\@empty%
   \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do%
     {\@citea\let\@citea\citepunct%
      \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@iden\@citeb}%
      \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{ieeetr}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}\fi%
      \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{1}%
      \fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \if@filesw\immediate\write12{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi%
      \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bf ?}%
         \@warning{Citation `\@citeb' in file `\@currentipfile'
             on page \thepage \space undefined}\G@refundefinedtrue}%
      {\hbox{\citeform{\csname b@\@citeb \@exele@b@citeb\endcsname}}}}}{#1}}
}{}% 2nd arg of \@ifundefined{@exele@b@citeb}

\def\@iden#1{#1}

\@ifundefined{citeform}{\let\citeform=\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{citepunct}{\def\citepunct{,\penalty\@m\ }}{}

\xdef\@savedjobname{\jobname}% save root file name as a macro
\let\@currentipfile\@savedjobname
\gdef\the@ipfilectr{}
\def\@exele@b@citeb{\the@ipfilectr}
\newcount\c@inputfile \global\c@inputfile=0

\gdef\@extra@binfo{}  % in case .aux files are left from old run.

\@ifundefined{reset@font}{\let\reset@font\relax}{}
\@ifundefined{G@refundefinedtrue}{\let\G@refundefinedtrue\relax}{}

\let\cb@bibliographystyle\bibliographystyle
\def\cb@roottest{2\ifx\the@ipfilectr\@empty 1\else2\fi}

\def\bibliographystyle#1{\if\cb@roottest\cb@bibliographystyle{#1}\fi}

\def\bibliography#1{\if\cb@roottest%
   \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}\fi%
   \fi \@input{\@currentipfile.bbl}}

\@ifundefined{PackageWarning}{\def\cb@warning{\@warning}}%
 {\def\cb@warning{\PackageWarning{chapterbib}}}

\let\@test@defiii\@testdef

\def\@testdef#1#2#3{%
  \if#1b\relax\@test@defiii b{#2\@extra@binfo}{#3}%
  \else \@test@defiii #1{#2}{#3}\fi%
}

\@ifundefined{bibname}{\def\bibname{Bibliography}}{}

% end of chapterbib section
}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}

\newcounter{myfigcount}
\newcounter{mytablecount}
\newcounter{myeqncount}
\newcounter{mychapcitecount}
\newcounter{mychaptercount}
\newcounter{myappendixcount}

\def\myusefigurespage{%
  \gdef\@myusefigurespage{true}
}

\def\myusetablespage{%
  \gdef\@myusetablespage{true}
}


\makeatletter

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{.2in}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0.25in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.6in}
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}

\brokenpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} % 1.3 spacing for tables and arrays

\def\myps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
  \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
}

\def\ele@chapapp{}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \Large\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}


\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\cl@chapter{%
  \setcounter{mychapcitecount}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@elt{section}\@elt{footnote}%
  }{%
    \@elt{equation}\@elt{figure}\@elt{footnote}\@elt{section}\@elt{table}%
  }}
\def\thefigure{%
  \addtocounter{myfigcount}{\value{figure}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@figure%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@figure%
  }}
\def\thetable{%
  \addtocounter{mytablecount}{\value{table}}%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@table%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\@arabic\c@table%
  }}
\def\theequation{%
  \@ifundefined{@nonsequential}{%
    \@arabic\c@equation%
  }{%
    \thechapter.\arabic{equation}%
  }}

% This xfloat definition was apparently originally created to allow single spacing
% within floats such as figures and tables.  Also, this was originally written for
% LaTeX2.09 and not updated for LaTeX2e.  Hence, with the setspace package now
% available, I'm commenting this definition out since there are known conflicts
% with this and using the color package.
%\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{\ifhmode \@bsphack\@floatpenalty -\@Mii\else
%   \@floatpenalty-\@Miii\fi\def\@captype{#1}\ifinner
%      \@parmoderr\@floatpenalty\z@
%    \else\@next\@currbox\@freelist{\@tempcnta\csname ftype@#1\endcsname
%       \multiply\@tempcnta\@xxxii\advance\@tempcnta\sixt@@n
%       \@tfor \@tempa :=#2\do
%                        {\if\@tempa h\advance\@tempcnta \@ne\fi
%                         \if\@tempa t\advance\@tempcnta \tw@\fi
%                         \if\@tempa b\advance\@tempcnta 4\relax\fi
%                         \if\@tempa p\advance\@tempcnta 8\relax\fi
%         }\global\count\@currbox\@tempcnta}\@fltovf\fi
%    \global\setbox\@currbox\vbox\bgroup
%    \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize
%    \boxmaxdepth\z@
%    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore}

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{\def\baselinestretch{1}\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
   \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}\@makefntext
    {\rule{\z@}{\footnotesep}\ignorespaces
      #1\strut}}}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{List of References
\@mkboth{}{}}\list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin
\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthebibliography=\endlist

\def\thesisbib{\chapter*{Bibliography
\@mkboth{}{}}\trivlist
 \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}
\let\endthesisbib=\endtrivlist

\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\pastdegrees#1{\gdef\@pastdegrees{#1}}
\def\degreename#1{\gdef\@degreename{#1}}
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\def\firstcommittee#1{\gdef\@firstcommittee{#1}}
\def\secondcommittee#1{\gdef\@secondcommittee{#1}}
\def\thirdcommittee#1{\gdef\@thirdcommittee{#1}}
\def\fourthcommittee#1{\gdef\@fourthcommittee{#1}}
\def\departmentchair#1{\gdef\@departmentchair{#1}}
\def\copyrightyear#1{\gdef\@copyrightyear{#1}} % \author, \title in report
\def\copyrightmonth#1{\gdef\@copyrightmonth{#1}}
\def\@title{}\def\@author{}\def\@dept{Systems and Computer Engineering}
\def\@supervisor{} \def\@firstcommittee{} \def\@secondcommittee{}
\def\@thirdcommittee{} \def\@fourthcommittee{} \def\@departmentchair{}
\def\@copyrightyear{\number\the\year}
\def\submitdate#1{\gdef\submitdate{#1}}

\def\@reffile{references}

\def\reffile#1{%
  \def\@reffile{#1}
}

\def\abstract#1{%
  \def\@abstract{#1}
}

\def\acknowledgements#1{%
  \def\@acknowledgements{#1}
}

\def\preface#1{%
  \def\@preface{#1}
}

\def\dedication#1{%
  \def\@dedication{#1}
}

\def\nomenclature#1{%
  \def\@nomenclature{#1}
}


\def\@bibliofileext{bib}
\def\@bibliofile{\jobname\@bibliofileext}

\def\@awork{%
\@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
  thesis
}{
  dissertation
}}

% Print title page
\def\titlep{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\bf\@title}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        by\\
        \mbox{}\\
        \mbox{}\\
        {\textbf{\@author}\@ifundefined{@pastdegrees}{}{, \textbf{\@pastdegrees}}}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        A \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{thesis proposal}{dissertation} submitted to the\\
    Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \bf{\@degreename}\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \begin{center}
        Electrical Engineering\\
        Department of \@dept\\
        University\\
        Unknown\\
        \submitdate\\
    \end{center}
    \mbox{}
    \begin{center}
        \copyright Copyright \\
        \@author, \@copyrightyear
    \end{center}\clearpage}


\long\def\signature#1{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{7in}
    \vspace{.4in}
    \hbox{\hfil\shortstack{\vrule width 4in height 0.4pt \\#1}}
  \end{minipage}}

\def\comprof{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.5in}
  \begin{flushright}
    \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
      Thesis
    }{
       Dissertation
    }
    Committee\\
    Supervisor
  \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}

% Print signature approval page
\def\signaturepage{%
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\begin{center}
    The undersigned hereby recommends to the\\
    Faculty of Graduate and Postdoctoral Affairs\\
    acceptance of the \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{thesis}{dissertation}\\
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    {\large\bf\@title}
\end{center}
\mbox{}
\begin{center}
    submitted by \textbf{\@author}\@ifundefined{@pastdegrees}{}{, \textbf{\@pastdegrees}}\\
    \mbox{}\\
    in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of\\
    \mbox{}\\
    \bf{\@degreename}\\
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
    \@ifundefined{@twocommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@threecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fourcommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
    }
    \@ifundefined{@fivecommittee}{}
    {
      & \signature\@firstcommittee\\
      & \signature\@secondcommittee\\
      & \signature\@thirdcommittee\\
      & \signature\@fourthcommittee\\
    }
     & \signature{\@departmentchair}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}{
  Engineering\\
  Department of \@dept\\
  University\\
  \@copyrightmonth, \@copyrightyear}
\end{center}}

\def\startingpages{%
  \setcounter{page}{0}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \titlep
  %\signaturepage
  \immediate\openout12=\@bibliofile.aux
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibstyle{cubiblio}}
  \immediate\write12{\string\bibdata{\@reffile}}
  \@ifundefined{@abstract}{}{
    \doourabstract{\@abstract}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@dedication}{}{
    \doourdedication{\@dedication}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@acknowledgements}{}{
    \doouracknowledgements{\@acknowledgements}
  }
  \@ifundefined{@preface}{}{
    \doourpreface{\@preface}
  }
  \contentspages
  \@ifundefined{@nomenclature}{}{
    \doournomenclature{\@nomenclature}
  }
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \pagestyle{myheadings}
}

\def\doourabstract#1{%
  \sloppy
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \@ifundefined{@phddissertation}{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }{
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \pagestyle{plain}
  }
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\def\doouracknowledgements#1{%
  \chapter*{Acknowledgments}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doourdedication#1{%
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \include{#1}
}

\def\doourpreface#1{%
  \chapter*{Preface}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
  \input{#1}
}

\def\doournomenclature#1{%
  \chapter*{Nomenclature}
  \phantomsection  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
  \input{#1}
  \newpage
}

\def\contentspages{\newpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
      \@ifundefined{@myusetablespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \phantomsection    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \listoftables
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
  \@ifundefined{@myusefigurespage}{}{
    {\addvspace{10pt}
    \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace
    \def\addvspace##1{}
    \phantomsection    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \listoffigures
    \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
  \newpage
  }
}

\def\newchapter#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{mychaptercount}
    \@ifundefined{@noleadpages}{
      \startingpages
    }{}
    \setcounter{mychaptercount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \phantomsection
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\ele@chapapp\space \protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \phantomsection
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}


\def\newappendix#1{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
    \setcounter{myappendixcount}{1}
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

\def\startappendix{%
  \def\ele@chapapp{Appendix}
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
     \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
    }{}
    \newpage
  }{}

  \appendix
  % This causes latex to number equations, tables, figures with
  % A-1, A-2, ...
%  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
%  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
}

% used for manuscript form chapter references
\def\refsforcb{%
  \@ifundefined{@wantmanuscript}{
  }{
    \ifnum0=\value{mychapcitecount}
      \relax
    \else
      \newpage
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of References}
%      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of References}
      \bibliography{\@reffile}
      \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
      \newpage
    \fi
  }
}

\def\biblio{%
  \ifnum0=\value{myappendixcount}
    \startappendix
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{myfigcount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusefigurespage}\fi
  \fi
  \ifnum0=\value{mytablecount}
    \relax
  \else
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\myusetablespage}\fi
  \fi
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
  \@input{\@bibliofile.bbl}
}

\def\bibliox{\bibliography{\@reffile}}

\@ifundefined{@norefbib}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\biblio
}{
  \let\@enddocumenthook\bibliox
}
```

Comment: Where would we obtain cuthesis.sty? We can't test your code without it. (Unless you can recreate your problem without it, in which case you should just remove it.)

Comment: Thanks, I just added it.

Comment: In `cuthesis.sty`, within the definition of `\thebibliography` there is a line "`\setlength{\baselineskip}{0.70\baselineskip}`".  (Don't ask my opinion of this; it is unprintable in polite company.)  That is what is compressing the vertical spacing.  Unfortunately, this may be the result of a bureaucratic decision, in which case you're skunked.  Before changing it, I'd advise you to determine the reason, and ask your advisor for assistance regarding a possible improvement.

Comment: By the way, the book title has been omitted from the formatted reference, making it very difficult for an interested reader to find the source.  (Under the circumstances, I don't have a very good opinion of this `.sty` file.)

Comment: Thank you so much @barbarabeeton I basically lost an entire day of work trying to fix this. Pretty sure my advisor won't care about the spacing. Increasing the 0.7 fixes the problem!

Comment: It's not your advisor that's going to care, it's your University. They often have stringent rules about how theses are supposed to be formatted. But maybe you'll get lucky and yours will be lax about it, because yeah, with 0.70 it does not look nice.

Comment: Ok, noted, thanks again!